# Global Function MVC3 different Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, controller, view

What Im looking for should be simple but it is eluding me. I have an MVC3 project with multiple controllers. In my global header I allow the user to change the language of the site, which the code is sitting in the home controller, to modify the localization information for the site. This works well once I am in the Home contoller, however, once I move out to the different controllers, the language link to change the localization just takes it back to the home controller and a different page. (I did have RedirectToAction("index") at the end of the localization code.

What I would like to do is from whatever controller I am on, call the set localization routine, and return the SAME page and controller that they are currently on, without redirecting them somewhere specific.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what if you move it to the master page and access it from the base controller class.  This way you have access to it across every class that accesses the base controller class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i'm missing some, but take out the RedirectToAction and just return the View().

It's pretty hard to know, since you didn't include any code to show what you are actually doing.  Vague descriptions don't help much.